# Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException using youtube player

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I have an android app which uses youtube player to play videos from youtube data api. Recently I'm getting this error in my crash report to frequently.

This is the crash report stack trace :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc/com.abc.videos.videoplayer.VideoPlayerActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: asc
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
Caused by android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: asc
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2432)
   at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2358)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2264)
   at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2675)
   at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1967)
   at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2321)
   at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2614)
   at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:224)
   at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:856)
   at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:2032)
   at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:1015)
   at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:970)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2396)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

My code for youtube player is here :

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener, View.OnClickListener,VideoPlayerContract.View {

private String TAG = "VideoPlayerActivity";

@BindView(R.id.youtube_player)
YouTubePlayerView mYouTubePlayerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_player);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    doLayout();
}

@Override
public void onFullscreen(boolean isfullscreen) {
    fullscreen = isfullscreen;
    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(fullscreen));
    if (!fullscreen){
        mToolBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(true);
        setRequestedOrientation(PORTRAIT_ORIENTATION);
    } else {
        mToolBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mAppBarLayout.setExpanded(false);
    }
    doLayout();
}

protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    mFeedInitiater = (FeedInitiater) intent.getSerializableExtra(Constants.FEEDINITIATER);
    mVideoID = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VIDEOID);
    videoTitle = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VIDEOTITLE);
    videoDescription = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VIDEODESCRIPTION);
    videoPublishedDate = UtilsFunctions.getFeedsDate(intent
            .getLongExtra(Constants.VIDEOPUBLISHEDDATE,0));
    videoViews = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.VIDEOCOUNT);
    playVideo();
     }

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    mYoutubePlayer = youTubePlayer;

    mYoutubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    mYoutubePlayer.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
    int controlFlags = mYoutubePlayer.getFullscreenControlFlags();
    controlFlags |= YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_ALWAYS_FULLSCREEN_IN_LANDSCAPE;
    mYoutubePlayer.setFullscreenControlFlags(controlFlags);
    mYoutubePlayer.setOnFullscreenListener(this);
    if (!wasRestored && mVideoID != null && !mVideoID.equals("")) {
        mYoutubePlayer.loadVideo(mVideoID);
    }
}

@Override
protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return mYouTubePlayerView;
}

private void doLayout() {
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams playerParams =
            (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mYouTubePlayerView.getLayoutParams();
    if (fullscreen && getResources().getConfiguration().orientation ==
            Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {

        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);

                final int flags =
                        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;

                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
                decorView
                        .setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility)
                            {
                                if((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0)
                                {
                                } else {
                                    mFeedsContent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    playerParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                                    playerParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    } else {
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
                getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
                playerParams.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                playerParams.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
                mFeedsContent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mYoutubePlayer != null)
        mYoutubePlayer.play();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mYoutubePlayer != null)
        mYoutubePlayer.pause();
}
@Override
public void playVideo() {
    mYouTubePlayerView.initialize(Constants.YOUTUBEDEVELOPERKEY,this);
}

@Override
public void setPresenter(VideoPlayerContract.Presenter presenter) {
    mPresenter = presenter;
    if (mFeedInitiater != FeedInitiater.FEEDS){
        mPresenter.loadVideoDetails(mVideoID);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    doLayout();
}
```

In manifest file I have declared this :

      `<activity android:name=".videos.videoplayer.VideoPlayerActivity"
 android:screenOrientation="sensor"android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>`

Is there any problem in my code or is this is the problem from youtube player and how to handle this problem?.